# Computing $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$ where $\alpha = dz + x\,dy$

Tags: differential-forms

Let $\alpha = dz + xdy$ be a one-form on $\mathbb R^3$. I would like to compute the wedge product $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$ as explicitly as possible but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

$$d\alpha = d(dz+x\,dy) = dx \wedge dy$$

so

\begin{align*}
\alpha\wedge d\alpha &= (dz+x\,dy)\wedge(dx\wedge dy)\\ 
&= dz\wedge dx\wedge dy + x\,dy\wedge dx\wedge dy\\ 
&= dz\wedge dx\wedge dy\\ 
&= dx\wedge dy\wedge dz.
\end{align*}

Is this correct ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This seems right to me